# Hibernate Search indexing only part of my entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate search on a project and the MassIndexer is only indexing part of my records. For example, in one table i have 601 records, but with my current settings it indexes only 300 documents.

My current settings are:

```
txtEm.createIndexer(  )
          .batchSizeToLoadObjects( 25 )
          .threadsToLoadObjects( 12 )
          .cacheMode( CacheMode.NORMAL )
          .idFetchSize( 150 )
          .transactionTimeout( 1800 )
          .startAndWait();
```

I've tested with `batchSizeToLoadObjects(1000)` and it seems to index all my records. But this project I'm working on is new, and the database has only a few records per table. I'm worried that when the tables grow, the entities won't  be indexed correctly.

Can anyone help with this? I've searched for some answers and configuration best practices, but couldn't find a solution.

Something that might help is the log generated when indexing the table. See below:

```
2018-07-02 17:45:52.794  INFO 648 --- [ntifierloader-1] o.h.s.b.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor  : HSEARCH000027: Going to reindex 601 entities
2018-07-02 17:45:52.812 ERROR 648 --- [ntifierloader-1] o.h.s.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler     : HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000211: An exception occurred while the MassIndexer was fetching the primary identifiers list

org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed!
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.managedClose(StatelessSessionImpl.java:378) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.close(StatelessSessionImpl.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.inTransactionWrapper(IdentifierProducer.java:118) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.run(IdentifierProducer.java:85) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.runWithErrorHandler(OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.java:69) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.ErrorHandledRunnable.run(ErrorHandledRunnable.java:32) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]

2018-07-02 17:45:52.883  INFO 648 --- [entityloader-10] o.h.s.b.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor  : HSEARCH000030: 200 documents indexed in 902 ms
2018-07-02 17:45:52.883  INFO 648 --- [entityloader-10] o.h.s.b.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor  : HSEARCH000031: Indexing speed: 221,729492 documents/second; progress: 25,54%
2018-07-02 17:45:52.886 ERROR 648 --- [entityloader-10] s.b.i.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer : HSEARCH000065: Error while rolling back transaction after Session is closed!

org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getTransaction(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.rollbackTransaction(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:205) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:182) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:117) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]
```

Also this `SessionException` happens and I couldn't find a solution for it.
The method that creates the index is annotated with `@Transacional`.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6 and Hibernate Search 5.6.4

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are somehow closing sessions while the mass indexer is still using them. Maybe you are using some exotic settings or integration that close a session automatically after a single transaction?

To find out if you are, either launch the mass indexing process in debug mode and put a breakpoint in `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl#close`, or set the log level for `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl` to TRACE. Then see whether a session is closed before the mass indexing stops: if so, there's something wrong in your code, and you should delay closing until mass indexing is done.

Comment: Debugging the app, I've been able to identify that the mass indexer runs the first batch of each entity than kills the session. And the number of records stored on the database is proportional to the `batchSizeToLoadObjects` and `threadsToLoadObjects` properties... For example: batch = 25 with 12 threads results in only 300 records being indexed... I'm using Spring Boot with it, and the SessionImpl class for hibernate is `StatelessSessionImpl.class`.. Is there any connection between them both?

Comment: This looks odd. You might want to double-check your transaction configuration. If it there's nothing particular there, maybe we could create a minimal reproducer and create a ticket on [our JIRA instance](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH) so we can have a look? We provide test case templates to help you do just that: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search

Answer (score 0):

Your database connections are being closed before Hibernate Search is done with them.

Are you running a connection pool? Ensure it's not prematurely reclaiming connections it thinks are abandoned.

Using c3p0 as an example, test this by setting
`hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout` to something high like 3600 in your configuration file.

If it now indexes correctly, you have your answer.